# Apache-poi ooxml Exception org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I'm trying to create a service that receives an array of data and creates an xlsx spreadsheet that will then be returned as base64.
However, I can't get the libs to work... I tried other versions and the errors were different.

Java 8,
weblogic 12,
intellijIDEA

[image: Dependency]

when the exception is thrown?

After invoking the service from the resource during instantiation new XSSFWorkbook();

`Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();`

Exception;

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(XSSFWorkbook.java:475)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:232)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:226)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:214)
```

Being able to help solve my problem and with the knowledge gained help other colleagues.

Comment: @pj-fanning help

Comment: Don't mix jars of different Apache POI versions (poi-ooxml 5.2.2 poi-scratchpad 5.2.4). See [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html) -> 19. Can I mix POI jars from different versions?.

Comment: But the exception tells that `CTWorkbook` has no member `Factory`. Have you compiled your code against poi-ooxml-lite 5.2.2? Or are you using pre compiled code which was compiled against ooxml-schemas? There it was `public static final class Factory` but now it is `final class Factory` only. Thus `CTWorkbook.Factory` of poi-ooxml-lite 5.2.2 ist different from `CTWorkbook.Factory` of ooxml-schemas. Try re-compiling your code against 5.2.2-version jars.

Comment: @AxelRichter 
It was my mistake, I'm all using the same version 5.2.2 and xmlbeans 5.0.3